# Is there an alternative way to solve this integral?

Tags: integration

I was given the integral
$$\int \frac{2}{e^{-x}+1}dx$$
Here is my method to get the (correct) solution:
$$\int \frac{2}{e^{-x}+1}dx$$
$$=2\int \frac{1}{e^{-x}+1}dx$$
$$=2\int \frac{e^xe^{-x}}{e^{-x}+e^xe^{-x}}dx$$
$$=2\int\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}dx$$
Let $u=e^x+1$ and $du=e^xdx$

So it becomes
$$2\int\frac{1}{u}du$$
$$=2 \ln|u|+c$$
$$=2 \ln(e^x+1)+c$$
Is there an alternative way to do this? My first thought was, when I got to
$$=2\int\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}dx$$
to write it as
$$=2\int\frac{e^x+1-1}{1+e^x}dx$$
as one would do for
$$=2\int\frac{x+1-1}{1+x}dx$$
but it becomes instead
$$2\int1-\frac{1}{1+e^x}dx$$
where it doesn't seem $u$-substitution would work.

Comment: I suppose that $s$ stands for $2$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you; that was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the [Bioche rules](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gles_de_Bioche):

Take $t = \tanh x/2$:

$$
dt = \frac {dx}{2\cosh^2x/2}
\\
\int \frac{e^x dx}{1 + e^x}
= \int \frac{e^{x/2} dx}{e^{-x/2} + e^{x/2}}
= \int \frac{e^{x/2} dx}{2\cosh x/2}
= \frac12 \int \frac{1 + e^{x} dx}{2\cosh^2 x/2}
$$

Then use the expression of $\tanh^{-1}$:
$$
\tanh^{-1}(t) = \frac 12\log\frac{1+t}{1-t}
\\ \implies  e^{x} = \frac{1+t}{1-t}
\\
%%%%%
\int \frac{e^x dx}{1 + e^x} =
\frac12 \int \left(1 +  \frac{1+t}{1-t} \right)dt
= \int  \frac{dt}{1-t} = -\log(1-t)
\\= -\log(1 - \tanh x/2) = -\log \frac 2{1 + e^{2x}}
= \log \frac {1 + e^{2x}}2 = \log (1 + e^x) + const.
$$

Comment: Brilliant. I had been trying to work with $\cosh x$ but I hadn't had any success.

Comment: Using the Bioche Rules shows the right path!